# Geometry error present only when writing shapefile to disk in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geometry

I have a complex shapefile that I am trying to use for a Difference spatial operation in QGIS (Madiera 3.4). When doing that I received an invalid geometry error.

Using the QGIS Check Validity tool for vector layers I can see that there are a handful of instances of "Hole lies outside shell" in my input shapefile.

If I then use the QGIS Fix Geometries tool under Vector Geometries and allow the tool to create a temporary scratch layer, the geometry errors are corrected and I can use that temporary scratch layer for my Difference operation. However, if I have the Fix Geometries tool write the output to disk and then use that layer for the Difference operation, the same "Hole lies outside shell" geometry error persists and the Fix Geometries operation apparently did not work.

Does anybody know why this would be the case?

The inputs are the same but I am missing something about why fixing the geometry errors in a scratch layer would work while saving the output would not.

Comment: Have you tried writing the output from fix geometry to a geopackage? Try buffering the output with a distance of 0

Comment: I have tried the buffer workaround to no avail, I have not tried writing to a geopackage, I can try that.

Comment: Interesting!  What happens if you Fix Geometries to a scratch file, then export the scratch file as a Geopackage layer?

Comment: Compare the project, temp layer, source and output shapefiles CRS and make sure the CRS is properly set everywhere. This kind of error can occur when reprojecting a layer (and maybe this is occurring with(out) on the fly reprojection)

Comment: Interesting yeah I will double check the CRS but I am pretty sure those are consistent throughout. @StuSmith yeah I tried that as well and interestingly if you export the scratch layer to disk and then do check validity again the geometry errors are present, even if they were not present in the scratch layer.

Comment: Can you make your data available for review?

Comment: Sorry I cannot make the whole thing available because it is in the process of being published. I have not resolved this issue but I found a workaround to deal with my issue another way.

Comment: Future readers may experience the same problem.  Out of respect for them, it would be professionally helpful if you could share your workaround here as an answer.  Personally, I'm still curious about your situation!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I mean I didn't resolve the issue, I just ended up doing a manual editing approach to deal with the geometry errors as I reached a point of diminishing returns trying to chase down this issue. I didn't want to put that as an accepted answer because its not really an answer to the question.